# PHP uso utf8_decode con msqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, webservice, utf-8

Buenas a todos,
Uso como hosting, HOSTINGER y tras haber intentado ponerme en contacto con el servicio técnico y no resolver el problema acudo a los expertos de este foro.

Estoy haciendo un webService en php, he conseguido ya que me almacene en la base de datos los caracteres con tildes o ñ, pero al enviarlos de vuelta no hay manera, me salen símbolos raros ...

Estoy haciendo esto:

```
        $consulta="SELECT emei, obsServicio FROM `voluntarioServicio` WHERE `id`= ".$id;
        $resultado= mysqli_query($link,$consulta);
        $arraySalida = array();
                while($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado) ):

                         $cadena = "{$registro['emei']};{$registro['obsServicio']}";
                         $arraySalida[]= $cadena;
                endwhile;
        echo utf8_decode( implode(":",$arraySalida));
```

Pero no debe funcionar del todo correcto ya que no decodifica el acento que sí aparece en phpMyAdmin, creo que la solución pasa por meter el utf_decode() en $regristo[''], pero no sé como...

He probado también:

```
echo implode(":",utf8_decode($arraySalida));
```

pero sigue mostrando caracteres raros

Alguna idea?

PD: también heprobado htmlspecialchars() y htmlentities() por probar mas funciones de decodificar

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usar el utf8_decode en el valor de registro antes de formar tu cadena:

```
$emei = utf8_decode($registro['emei']);
$obsServicio = utf8_decode($registro['obsServicio']);
$arraySalida[] = "{$emei};{$obsServicio}";
```

Ya no usas la variable $cadena y no olvides quitar el utf8_decode en tu linea echo.

Comment: Tampoco funciona así, creo que probaré con htmlentiies() o alguna otra función, el caso es que el utf8_encode() funciona porque sino no me metería los acentos en la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `mysqli_set_charset` al momento de crear tu conexión, ya que esta función especifíca un caracter por default para tu envio de datos.

Intena poner esto despues de hacer tu conexión

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");//recibe tu conexion creada y el caracter a especificar
```

Comment: Ya lo tenia puesto, justo después de realizar la conexión y nada, tambien tengo puesto header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); , muchas gracias por intentar ayudar